# Get File Contents inner data retrieve

Tags: php, jquery

I am developing a whois app for my self to maintain expiry dates of my country level domains (PK). Our PKNIC provider doesn't allow any API or XML to get any such data so i googled found this code that could work now i need a little more code to retrieve only expiry date into a text box.

```
<?php
$postdata = http_build_query(
array(
    'name' => 'google.com.pk',
)
);

$opts = array('http' =>
array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postdata
)
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://pk5.pknic.net.pk/pk5/lookup.PK', false, $context);
//print_r($result);
echo $result;
?>
```

Using the above code i get the results something like this..

```
  <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td background="img/bg_diagnol.gif"><div align="right" class="style2">Create Date:</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td background="img/square.gif"><span xclass="TD_small">2003-03-05</span></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td background="img/bg_diagnol.gif"><div align="right" class="style2">Expire Date: </div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td background="img/square.gif">2013-03-05</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td background="img/bg_diagnol.gif">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td background="img/square.gif">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td background="img/bg_diagnol.gif"><div align="right" class="style2">Agent Organization:</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td background="img/square.gif">MarkMonitor       <!--
     &nbsp; &nbsp; <span class="footer"></span> 
     -->
        </td>
```

Now i just want to retrieve the Domain Expiry Date, is it possible ?
Something maybe like

$('td').find('Expire Date:').after().html

Or is there any regx i can search for date format and copy into text box ?

Comment: If the output is guaranteed to be well-formed, an XML parser would be easier than regex in your case.

Comment: Any example you can give under my case ?

Comment: This should get you started: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like weirdly formatted xml to return (looks like it's more for display than consumption), but you can still do it.  `.after` is for DOM manipulation.

```
$(":contains(Expire Date)").parent().next().next().html();
```

Comment: I think OP wants a PHP solution for the extraction.

Comment: Yes it will. but after it reaches the client side.  From the question, it looks like he wants to extract and return only some particular info from the full HTML received.

Comment: Bingoo..! This Line Works

$(":contains(Expire Date)").parent().next('td').next().html();

Comment: Which means I was wrong! OP just wanted to extract the info, not particular about server or client side. :-)

Comment: As there were NO ID or CLASSES used.. the only way to get data is this way.. this is what i think

Comment: @Amanullah - This answer is perfectly valid since your data is rather small, but in future cases like this, consider sending to the client only that much data that is actually needed on the client.